# How to compare two Joda time Periods

Tags: java, jodatime

It does not seem straighforward.

I am trying this:

```
@Override
public int compare(Period o1, Period o2) {
    return o1.toStandardDays().getDays() > o2.toStandardDays().getDays() ? -1 : (o1.toStandardDays().getDays() == o2.toStandardDays().getDays() ? 0 : 1);
}
```

But I get this exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot convert to Days as this period contains months and months vary in length
    at org.joda.time.Period.checkYearsAndMonths(Period.java:1455)
    at org.joda.time.Period.toStandardDays(Period.java:1314)
```

I hoped `Peroid` would have an `isLongerThan(Period p)` method.

Comment: Is "1 month, 30 days" longer or shorter than "2 months"?

Comment: @raticulin: and "undefined" is exactly what you get. It's expressed as an exception.

Comment: @Joachim 'undefined' would be you don't know if you get "1 month, 30 days" or "2 months". An exception is not.

Comment: @raticulin that is clearly not their definition of `undefined`, nor is it mine. When software says "under such and such conditions, the behavior is undefined" you really cannot expect **anything.** `undefined` might mean that a computation returns an unexpected value, or that it throws an exception, or that it causes your computer sprout wings and flee.

Comment: @matt is not 'the definition' or is not 'your definition'?

Comment: @raticulin "their" meaning "the JodaTime authors"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [the Joda Documentation](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/Period.html):

> To compare the actual duration of two periods, convert both to durations using `toDuration`, an operation that emphasises that the result may differ according to the date you choose.

The two `toDuration` methods are [`BasePeriod#toDurationTo(ReadableInstant)`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/base/BasePeriod.html#toDurationTo%28org.joda.time.ReadableInstant%29) and [`BasePeriod#toDurationFrom(ReadableInstant)`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/base/BasePeriod.html#toDurationFrom%28org.joda.time.ReadableInstant%29). This means that you **must** choose either a start or end instant of this period in order to be able to compute its duration.

If that is a problem for you, then **you might want to directly use [`Duration`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/Duration.html)** instead of `Period`.

Comment: @Benj thanks for the edit, but the term [JavaDoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc) is widely used to refer to the document generator system and/or its output. Many projects and libraries provide links to JavaDoc pages, which are generated from running the JavaDoc tool. I don't think most people find the term confusing or unclear as to whether or not "JavaDoc" refers to the API documentation for Java SE.

Comment: Maybe because I'm French ? Here a lot of people are using (in english) "JavaDoc" to refer to the Oracle (formerly Sun) online documentation or the books *first*, then the library API. I learned something at least, i'll care that ;) +1

Answer (score 2):

As Matt Ball also explained in his answer, to compare 2 periods you need to convert them to a duration first. Durations are relative to a certain point in time, so you need to do something like this:

```
public static boolean isLonger(Period p1, Period p2) {
   Instant now = Instant.now();
   Duration d1 = p1.toDurationTo(now);
   Duration d2 = p2.toDurationTo(now);
   return d1.isLongerThan(d2);
}

public static boolean isShorter(Period p1, Period p2) {
   Instant now = Instant.now();
   Duration d1 = p1.toDurationTo(now);
   Duration d2 = p2.toDurationTo(now);
   return d1.isShorterThan(d2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a method that should be able to compare two Periods to the nearest day (I didn't care about hours and minutes):

```
private int comparePeriods(Period period1, Period period2)
{
    if (period1.getYears() != period2.getYears())
    {
        return Integer.compare(period1.getYears(), period2.getYears());
    }
    if (period1.getMonths() != period2.getMonths())
    {
        return Integer.compare(period1.getMonths(), period2.getMonths());
    }
    if (period1.getWeeks() != period2.getWeeks())
    {
        return Integer.compare(period1.getWeeks(), period2.getWeeks());
    }
    if (period1.getDays() != period2.getDays())
    {
        return Integer.compare(period1.getDays(), period2.getDays());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that this method expects both periods to be normalised or it will not give accurate results.