# Joda-Time all in minutes

Tags: java, jodatime

Is there a hidden way to get a [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) period in minutes (or any other)

Right now I do:

```
(period.getHours()*60 + period.getMinutes() + roundTwoDecimals((double)(period.getSeconds()/60)))
double roundTwoDecimals(double d) {
        DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    return Double.valueOf(twoDForm.format(d));
}
```

But for some reason I think there could be an easier way.

EDIT: My times will be max hours, and will never be days. This is my first time with Joda-Time.

Comment: The number of minutes in a period depends on it being associated with a particular instant in time. What if the period were to span a leap year, or a leap second? The resulting values would be different. Is it possible for you to use a [`Duration`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html) instead?

Comment: For some clarification, have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6467975/29995) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2653655/29995).

Comment: Thanks for the links, even if I dont use duration this time they provided valuable knowledge.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since `Period`s are defined by individual component fields (e.g. 5 years, 7 weeks), they cannot (easily) be converted directly to, say, minute values without first associating them with a particular instant in time.

For example, if you have a period of 2 months, how many minutes does it contain? In order to know that, you need to know which two months. Perhaps:

- June and July? (30 + 31 = 61 days)
- July and August? (31 + 31 = 62 days)
- February of a leap year and March? (29 + 31 = 60 days)

Each one of those is going to have a different number of minutes.

That in mind, there are a few ways to approach this. Here are a couple:

1. If you're *guaranteed* that your `Period` won't contain months (or higher), you can just use [`toStandardSeconds()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html#toStandardSeconds%28%29):

   ```
   Period period = new Period(60, 40, 20, 500);
   System.out.println(period.toStandardSeconds().getSeconds() / 60.0);

   // outputs 3640.3333333333335
   ```

   However, if you do end up with a month value in your `Period`, you'll get (per the javadoc) an `UnsupportedOperationException`:

   > java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot convert to Seconds as this period contains months and months vary in length
2. Otherwise, you can associate the `Period` with an instant in time and use a [`Duration`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html):

   ```
   Period period = new Period(1, 6, 2, 2, 5, 4, 3, 100);

   // apply the period starting right now
   Duration duration = period.toDurationFrom(new DateTime());

   System.out.println(duration.toStandardSeconds().getSeconds() / 60.0);

   // outputs 810964.05 (when right now is "2012-01-09T13:36:43.880-06:00")
   ```

Note that #2 will print different values depending on the day the code runs. But that's just the nature of it.

As an alternative, you might consider just using `Duration`s from the start (if possible) and not using `Period`s at all.

Comment: My program "durations" will only be between minutes and a couple of hours, and reading the answers seems like I should had gone durations from the start. But considering that is already written do you think method #1 would just be an easy fix? One last quesiton if I use period.toStandardminutes() wouldnt it be simpler? No need to add, and multiply the hours.

Comment: @Juan - #1 will probably be a good enough fix for your situation; it might not hurt to add a check around it for months (to avoid the unexpected `UnsupportedOperationException`) in case they happen to sneak in. As for `toStandardMinutes()`: I was using seconds because A) I wasn't sure if `toStandardMinutes()` would truncate the partial seconds, and B) if you needed those partial seconds. If you're okay with the truncation, using `toStandardMinutes()` is probably fine.

Comment: @Juan - *"Tried...but didnt work"* - how? Can you update your question with the code you tried, the result, and why it wasn't what was expected?

Comment: Okay, work. Seems there was a little error on a previous statement. Works using: roundTwoDecimals((double)(period.toStandardSeconds().getSeconds())/60)
I had to leave the roundTwoDecimals and cast it to double, but still better

Comment: This accepted answer is needlessly complex. Look at the [`Minutes`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Minutes.html) class, as shown in [my answer](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/index.html). A simple single line of code.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can easily get minutes from a Joda-Time [Period](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html) object.

```
int minutes = Minutes.standardMinutesIn( period ).getMinutes();
```

---

FYI, the *Joda-Time* project is now in [maintenance-mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode). Now recommended to migrate to its official successor: the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310, and build into Java 8+.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, convert from seconds to minutes like in the accepted answer is not needed, this should be the accepted  answer by its simplicity

Answer (score 2):

You can try `(double) period.getMillis()/60000` and reformat it.

Comment: This will only return the millisecond *component* of the period, and will disregard the other fields.

Comment: To clarify, doing `new Period(1, 6, 2, 2, 5, 4, 3, 100).getMillis()` will only return `100`, and not the full length of the period (i.e. summed fields).